# PhoneGap Android Softkeyboard Shifts elements up

Tags: css, xml, html, position, cordova

Using phonegap I have a textarea, a button, and two images. When I click in the textarea - the softkeyboard initiates but it shifts the elements mentioned above upward above the softkeyboard. I need these to stay where they are and behind the keyboard.

i've tried managing the position: 'fixed' ,'absolute' but still nothing. I feel like I might need to make a change in the XML. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I found it... in the XML under "activity" you need to add this line:

XML

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```